# Retrieve a Folder’s Items with offset and limit

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to use the get items from a folder (below) with the limit param.
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?offset=50&limit=50

so let say i have 103 items in the folder, when i use the above call i get this (below). if  i do the same without the offiset and limit, the returned json is the all 103 items.

{
  "item_collection": {
    "total_count": 103,
    "entries": []
  },
  "page_size": "50",
  "offset": "50"
}

Am I missing something??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. The `offset` is corresponding to the **number of pages in** as opposed to the **number of items in**.

We're working on fixing this now and will hopefully have it resolved soon.